# Change border color of Combobox in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

How do I change the border color of a WPF combo box, I've tried everything but it remains the same.

[image: ComboBox with default border]

My Mark up:

```
<ComboBox Canvas.Left="12" Canvas.Top="44" Height="32"Name="cmbDeviceList" Width="158" Foreground="#000000" BorderBrush="#2071B9" BorderThickness="2" FontFamily="Microsoft Sans Serif" FontSize="15" IsEditable="True" IsReadOnly="True" />
```

Comment: Use property BorderBrush???

Comment: Used it but of no use

Comment: How did you use it? Please post the markup.

Comment: Maybe you have your combo box style overriden, so it ignores `BorderBrush`. Please include your style if it is so.

Comment: hm, I don't have a style in my window that overrides it, the border does not show up... I also set border thickness

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the property `BorderBrush` to the desired color or brush:

```
<ComboBox Margin="10" BorderBrush="Red">
  <ComboBoxItem>No Device Selected</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of combo box with red border]

Comment: @Deepak: Yes, I did and it has a blue border. You can check too. Create a new WPF application and paste your markup into the new project to see for yourself. My best bet as to why you are unable to change the border color is because the control template is modified in the default style for a combo box like Michał Kędrzyński suggested.

Answer (score 2):

The below XAML snippet is for combobox. The BorderBrush will define the color and Border Thickness will define the thickness of line

```
<ComboBox Width="200" Height="30" BorderBrush="Blue" BorderThickness="3"></ComboBox>
```